# Laravel 5.3 : kcfinder Image upload not working

Tags: php, laravel, ckeditor, image-uploading, kcfinder

I put these lined of code in `ckeditor` config file.

```
// ...
config.filebrowserBrowseUrl = '/kcfinder/browse.php?opener=ckeditor&type=files';
config.filebrowserImageBrowseUrl = '/kcfinder/browse.php?opener=ckeditor&type=images';
config.filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl = '/kcfinder/browse.php?opener=ckeditor&type=flash';
config.filebrowserUploadUrl = '/kcfinder/upload.php?opener=ckeditor&type=files';
config.filebrowserImageUploadUrl = '/kcfinder/upload.php?opener=ckeditor&type=images';
config.filebrowserFlashUploadUrl = '/kcfinder/upload.php?opener=ckeditor&type=flash';
// ...
```

As a result `KCFinder` Buttons (link, upload, browse, send-it-to-server) show properly in the `textarea`. But when I send the image to the server, it shows

```
Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the
referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the 
author of that page about the error.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
Error 404
localhost
Apache/2.4.18 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2e PHP/7.0.1
```

In that time `url` shows

```
http://localhost/kcfinder/browse.php?opener=ckeditor&type=images&
CKEditor=post&CKEditorFuncNum=1&langCode=en
```

I opened a new `Tab` in the Browser adding my website name (ewt) in the url. It opens the page properly and I could upload image from there accordingly.

The Changed url is: (I add ewt between loacalhost and kcfinder)

```
http://localhost/ewt/kcfinder/browse.php?opener=ckeditor&type=images&
CKEditor=post&CKEditorFuncNum=1&langCode=en
```

How can I add ewt in the url at ckeditor's config file?
I tried

```
{{url()}}, base_url(), url()
```

etc. but not work.
I need help...

Comment: Did you install any package to include kcfinder and ckeditor to your app?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I guess that there is a problem with path.

```
config.filebrowserBrowseUrl = '/kcfinder/browse.php?opener=ckeditor&type=files';
config.filebrowserImageBrowseUrl = '/kcfinder/browse.php?opener=ckeditor&type=images';
config.filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl = '/kcfinder/browse.php?opener=ckeditor&type=flash';
config.filebrowserUploadUrl = '/kcfinder/upload.php?opener=ckeditor&type=files';
config.filebrowserImageUploadUrl = '/kcfinder/upload.php?opener=ckeditor&type=images';
config.filebrowserFlashUploadUrl = '/kcfinder/upload.php?opener=ckeditor&type=flash';
```

Remove `/` from starting of every path:

```
config.filebrowserBrowseUrl = 'kcfinder/browse.php?opener=ckeditor&type=files';
config.filebrowserImageBrowseUrl = 'kcfinder/browse.php?opener=ckeditor&type=images';
config.filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl = 'kcfinder/browse.php?opener=ckeditor&type=flash';
config.filebrowserUploadUrl = 'kcfinder/upload.php?opener=ckeditor&type=files';
config.filebrowserImageUploadUrl = 'kcfinder/upload.php?opener=ckeditor&type=images';
config.filebrowserFlashUploadUrl = 'kcfinder/upload.php?opener=ckeditor&type=flash';
```

If still this not work, you can trace this path issue with help of browser extension say Firebug to check http request.

**Some helpful web extension**:

1. [Fiddler](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fiddler/hkknfnifmbannmgkdliadghepbneplka?hl=en)
2. [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/?src=search)
3. [Tamper data](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tamper-data/)

Hope this help you!

Answer (score 0):

From your information, `kcfinder` is located under `ewt` folder which is under the root of your website. So, change your config to:

```
config.filebrowserBrowseUrl = '/ewt/kcfinder/browse.php?opener=ckeditor&type=files';
config.filebrowserImageBrowseUrl = '/ewt/kcfinder/browse.php?opener=ckeditor&type=images';
config.filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl = '/ewt/kcfinder/browse.php?opener=ckeditor&type=flash';
config.filebrowserUploadUrl = '/ewt/kcfinder/upload.php?opener=ckeditor&type=files';
config.filebrowserImageUploadUrl = '/ewt/kcfinder/upload.php?opener=ckeditor&type=images';
config.filebrowserFlashUploadUrl = '/ewt/kcfinder/upload.php?opener=ckeditor&type=flash';
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**
I added full url like these

```
// ...
config.filebrowserBrowseUrl = 'http://localhost/ewt/kcfinder/browse.php?opener=ckeditor&type=files';
config.filebrowserImageBrowseUrl = 'http://localhost/ewt/kcfinder/browse.php?opener=ckeditor&type=images';
config.filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl = 'http://localhost/ewt/kcfinder/browse.php?opener=ckeditor&type=flash';
config.filebrowserUploadUrl = 'http://localhost/ewt/kcfinder/upload.php?opener=ckeditor&type=files';
config.filebrowserImageUploadUrl = 'http://localhost/ewt/kcfinder/upload.php?opener=ckeditor&type=images';
config.filebrowserFlashUploadUrl = 'http://localhost/ewt/kcfinder/upload.php?opener=ckeditor&type=flash';
// ...
```

Now the problem is **Solved**.